# Styling pie chart label in flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I need to have style for labels in a pie chart.

I passed htmltext(ex:- < b>< i>Chart Label< /i>< /b>) in a label function to column chart and bar chart . I am able to get the label in bold and italic(***Chart Label***).

But in pie chart the label is showing up as htmltext as it is(< b>< i>Chart Label< /i>< /b>)

How can i get this done?I m struggling with this issue for two days.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you just want to have bold/italic styles applied to your labels this is what you should do:

```
 <mx:Style>
    .boldOnly {
        fontSize:9;
        fontWeight:bold;
        labelPosition:inside;
    }

    .italicOnly {
        fontSize:9;
        fontStyle:italic;
        labelPosition:inside;
        labelAlign:top;
    }

  .boldAndItalic{
        fontSize:9;
        fontStyle:italic;
        fontWeight:bold;
        labelPosition:inside;
        labelAlign:top;
    }
  </mx:Style>
```

Declare the style tag above in your mxml code, and then in your pie-chart mxml tag do the following:

For only bold:

```
<mx:PieChart id="chart"   dataProvider="{expenses}"   showDataTips="false" styleName="boldOnly" >
```

For only italic :

```
<mx:PieChart id="chart"   dataProvider="{expenses}"   showDataTips="false" styleName="italicOnly" >
```

For bold and italic

```
<mx:PieChart id="chart"   dataProvider="{expenses}"   showDataTips="false" styleName="boldAndItalic">
```

This is there is no need to change the label property of each label appearing in the chart.

Please update this ASAP if this does not work.

Comment: i am using htmlText because i need to have an image beside the label with the style like < img src='/images/ButOpen.gif'/> + "<i><b>Chart Label</b></i>"

Comment: If you just want an image beside the label, you can use the the image tag right from within flex, e.g <image src="/images/ButOpen.gif" height='14' width='14' /><label text='icon beside label'/>